# SQL Server 2008 R2 Schema Files

Tags: sql-server-2008

How do I run schema (`.sql`) files? Do I have to import it or execute it somewhere? Any help or explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file with SQL Server Management Studio. You should be able to double-click on the .sql file and it will open in SSMS by default. You'll be prompted to connect to a server, then you can execute the script using <kbd>F5</kbd>.